# Logithèque - Translation

Tags: translation

I would like to translate the French term `Logithèque` in English. This word is used in the context of a **collection of software like the Android Store or Apple Store**. But those are not to be paid for.

The term `Software Library` come the quickest to my mind, but it also seems applicable for Software Libraries such as `.dll`, `.so`, etc. files

How would I be able to translate "Logithèque" in any way that would be correct for a native speaker?

Comment: If you think that "Software Library" may be ambiguous, use "software repository", or just "repository" if the context is clearly related to software. To convey the idea of a server, a centralized service, the term "Central Repository" would fit.

Comment: Are you referring to the software that runs the store, or the software that can be obtained from the store?

Comment: The answer is quite hard to give. I'm referring to the "group of application" that can be obtained in a store. Is this clear enough ?

Answer (score 2):

**Software library** is correct according to the Oxford English Dictionary.

English often has multiple meanings for words. It's one of the delightful features of the language.

In this case it would be very obvious what meaning should be read, based on context.

Comment: *Software library* is correct. Historically, these were also called *Shareware libraries*. If you want to distinguish from the now technical meaning of library, you could say *Software archive*.

Answer (score 0):

**App[lication] Library** or **Program Library** would both be understood, and at the same time are distinct from a library one would link to.